# How to parse RSS feeds in a webpage

Tags: javascript, rss

I would like to create a simple webpage that parses some RSS feeds and summarizes the information.

I thought that this would be possible with a minimal html/javascript solution that can either be run locally on my computer or hosted as a static webapp (e.g. in github pages) and I wouldn't need a backend server. However, I got stuck when some RSS feeds are not parsed because I am getting blocked by CORS policy restrictions. I am wondering if there is something wrong with my implementation or there is another more appropriate way of getting the RSS feeds parsed.

Here is a minimal example of my problem:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>example</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

and here is the script.js

```
//const RSS_URL = 'https://status.grafana.com/history.rss'; //works
const RSS_URL = 'https://azure.status.microsoft/en-us/status/'; //doesn't work
fetch(RSS_URL)
  .then(response => response.text())
  .then(str => new window.DOMParser().parseFromString(str, "application/xml"))
  .then(data => console.log(data))
```

Comment: thanks @Yogi, this is what I was missing! Unfortunately there isn't always a json feed and having a cloud function seems to me a waste of resources warming up unecessariy our planet ;)